# Hadoop mapreduce design / Routing mapper and reducer on one job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce, chaining, mapper

I want to make an mapreduce design like this inside one job.

Example :

I want on a job: *************************************************************

[Mapper A] ---> [Mapper C]

[Mapper B] ---> [Reducer B]

After that [Reducer B] ---> [Mapper C]

[Mapper C] ---> [Reducer C] ******************************************************************************

So [Mapper A] & [Reducer B] ---> [Mapper C]. And next [Mapper C] continue to [Reducer C]. I want all scenario above run on one job.

It's like a routing inside one mapreduce job. I can route many mappers to particular reducer and continue it to other mapper than reducer again inside one job. I need your suggest bro

Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

--Edit starts
To simplify the problem lets say you have three jobs JobA, JobB, JobC each comprising of a map and a reduce phase.
Now you want to use mapper output of JobA in mapper task of JobC, so JobC just needs to wait for JobA to finish its map task, you can use MultipleOutputs class in your JobA to preserve/write map phase output at a location which JobC can poll for. 
--Edit ends

Programatically you can do something like below code, where getJob() should be defined in respective Map-reduce class,  where you specify configuration, DistributedCache, input formats etc.

```
main () {
    processMapperA();
    processMapReduceB();
    processMapReduceC();
}

processMapperA()
{
    // configure the paths/inputs needed, for example sake I am taking two paths
    String path1 = "path1";
    String path2 = "path2";
    String[] mapperApaths = new String[]{path1, path2};

    Job mapperAjob = MapperA.getJob(mapperApaths, <some other params you want to pass>);
    mapperAjob.submit();
    mapperAjob.waitForCompletion(true);
}

processMapReduceB()
{
    // init input params to job
    .
    .
    Job mapReduceBjob = MapReduceB.getJob(<input params you want to pass>);
    mapReduceBjob.submit();
    mapReduceBjob.waitForCompletion(true);
}
processMapReduceC()
{
    // init input params to job
    .
    .
    Job mapReduceCjob = MapReduceC.getJob(<input params you want to pass like outputMapperA, outputReducerB>);
    mapReduceCjob.submit();
    mapReduceCjob.waitForCompletion(true);
}
```

To gain more control on the workflow, you can consider using Oozie or SpringBatch.

With Oozie you can define workflow.xml's and schedule execution of each job as required.
SpringBatch can also be used for same but would require some coding and understanding, if you have a background to it, it can be used straightaway.
--Edit starts
Oozie is a workflow management tool, it allows you to configure and schedule jobs.
--Edit Ends

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank a lot for ur help bro, 
but I want to ask cause I don't fully understand
how can mapper A continue it's process to mapReduce C

And if I want to use Oozie, it is dificult to imlpement it in Hadoop Mapreduce ?

Thanks....

Comment: I'm sorry I want to ask again ahahaha
I mean can ozzie route mapper and reducer like that on one job, or oozie use to routing job to another job.

And according to you which are better, many map and reducer inside one job, or many mapper and reducer on many jobs.

Thanks a lot......

Comment: please check I have updated the answer, I will suggest you to write some working code, try out things and then post the problem you are stuck in.

Comment: beforely thanks for your help
But, I mean can I make mapper & reducer A, B, C run on one job.
Cause I've searched and tried before, when I use more than 1 reducer on one job, that gonna be error

I need your suggest bro.....Thanks a lot

Comment: please check I have added sample code here - https://github.com/mbaxi/stackoverflow/tree/master/hadoop/hadoop/src/main/java/com/mbaxi/hadoop

Comment: I'm sorry bro
If I'm not wrong, I think your sample use more than one job to do it
I only want to know whether the case like above can be done only on one job to minimize the process load, memory, time, etc....

Sorry bro, If I'm hard to know what you're really mean....hahaaha
Explain to me bro...Thanks....

Comment: I dont think its possible to chain different map reduce tasks in single job.